# Convert IEnumerable<IGrouping<T, K>> to IEnumerable<K>

Tags: c#, linq

What is the best way to convert `IEnumerable<IGrouping<T,K>>` to `IEnumerable<K>` ?

It seems this way will work:

```
myEnumerable = myEnumerableOfGroups
    .Select( group => group.AsEnumerable)
    .Aggregate((enumA, enumB) => enumA.Concat(enumB));
```

is there a more efficient way to do it ?

Comment: That depends on what you want to accomplish.  Are you just wanting to iterate all of the K objects in each grouping sequentially, that is undo the grouping?

Comment: Watch out @cdhowie, if you stop to ask questions you'll miss the rep train. Three answers in the same second.

Comment: @Rawling I'd rather have a clearly documented question than a few silly rep points.

Comment: Try to answer a question containing `IEnumerable` in the topic,
Andddd its 10 answer in the same second

Comment: @Rawling Haha - love "rep train".

Comment: Yes, the purpose was to undo the grouping, and it seems SelectMany is exactly that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
myEnumerable = myEnumerableOfGroups.SelectMany(group => group);
```

The MSDN page for this overload of `SelectMany` is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Wow, that was fast :), Thanks

Comment: @MichaelB It's a shame that the fastest reaction to such a question is "rep!" not "maybe it's a duplicate".

Comment: @MichaelB That tells you just how little research you did before asking your question, not how skilled of a poster any of the people who answered the question were.