# Lambda Expression Group by

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a problem with Group by in lambda expression, Lets say I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT [name] FROM [db].[dbo].[table] GROUP BY [key]
```

I want to get the same result using lambda expression, I tried this :

```
IQueryable<table> query = context.table.GroupBy(s => s.key);
```

But I get "missing cast" error.

What I miss here?

Comment: GroupBy return type is  System.Linq.IQueryable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>.

Comment: @vc74 I edit the questions

Comment: @mami can you explain please.

Comment: You are missing the select. Let me find the dupe for you.

Comment: related: [How to get values from IGrouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521025/how-to-get-values-from-igrouping), [Convert IEnumerable<IGrouping<T, K>> to IEnumerable<K>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122927/convert-ienumerableigroupingt-k-to-ienumerablek?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get values from IGrouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521025/how-to-get-values-from-igrouping)

Comment: The solution is to find the return type of GroupBy and goes from there in your research. Yes, IGrouping herits from IEnumerable

Comment: Your select will fail? You are getting name but group by key?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
IQueryable<table> query = context.table..AsQueryable().GroupBy(s => s.key)..SelectMany(x => x);
```